# 現在稼働中のPHPサイトにWordPressを共存させたくない場合のサーバ構成について（ドメインも同じにしたい）

Tags: php, wordpress

表題の通りですが、現在稼働中のPHPサイトにWordPressを追加してコラム機能を追加したかったのですが、
PHPのバージョンが古い為、WordPress用にサーバを新設しようと考えています。
ドメインが別なら楽なのですが、ドメインも統一したく、図のようなシステム構成は可能そうでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: URLの振り分けは基本的にロードバランサで行います。利用しているロードバランサーはどのようなサービスor製品を使っていますか？そのロードバランサーでURLの振り分け機能はついてますか？

Comment: ロードバランサのURL振り分けについては調度インフラ担当に確認中です。コメントありがとうございます。